# How to export a Big Cartel shop theme that has been customized?

Tags: themes, bigcartel

I have a big cartel store that I have customized, but I cannot figure out how to export it to transfer it to another store.

Is it not possible, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the export options available for your Big Cartel store data are downloading order details, and your customization settings.

**To download a copy of your store customization settings:**

Head to 'Customize design' > 'Advanced', and click "Download current theme" at the bottom of the page.

> **To download your orders as a .csv file:**
>
> Head to the 'Orders' page in your Admin, and click "Export CSV" at the
>   bottom of the page.
>
> **To import the theme back into Big Cartel:**
>
> The only way to ‘import’ the theme is by copying each page’s code from
>   the theme files and pasting them into the corresponding pages in your
>   Big Cartel admin. The option to import a theme with the click of a
>   button is currently not possible, but hopefully in the future Big
>   Cartel will make that option possible. [[source](http://themefiend.com/faq/)]